# Cleanup backups with spatie/laravel-backup return error ...mailbox database is offline

Tags: smtp, laravel-8, laravel-backup

I have a laravel 8.75 project with spatie/laravel-backup 6.14.

Backups and cleanups works well until today.

Backups still works fine but cleanups return this error (on a notification email):

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "432", with message "432 4.3.2 STOREDRV; mailbox database is offline;
STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:WrongServerException.MapiExceptionMdbOffline; 
Failed to process message due to a transient exception with message [BeginDiagnosticData]Cannot open mailbox.
```

The mailbox I use is reachable and I verified name and password.

I receive this error by email so the smtp configuration seems to be ok.

I have to precise that the cleaning is done well despite sending this error.

Moreover the backups success notifications are still sent.

I have no idea what is suddenly wrong...

Does anyone have an idea?